# Displaying Content From Custom Post Type with Page Templates

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I'm developing a site for a client where the homepage is built like a one-page scroller, but I also need the functionality of additional pages outside of the single homepage. I've built a custom post type for these sections and used this code to display them on the homepage.

```
<?php query_posts( array('post_type'=>'homepage', 'posts_per_page' => 1000, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
        global $post;
        $slug = $post->post_name;
        locate_template(
            array(
                "template-$slug.php",
                'template-main.php'
            ), true
        );
    ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

So, as you can see, this is automatically pulling content and displaying it using page templates based on the post slug, however, I need to allow my client to display the content based on a page template chosen in a dropdown and I've used this code to create a dropdown UI that displays the page templates.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_page_attributes_meta_box' );
function add_custom_page_attributes_meta_box(){
global $post;
    if ( 'page' != $post->post_type && post_type_supports($post->post_type, 'page-attributes') ) {
        add_meta_box( 'custompageparentdiv', __('Template'), 'custom_page_attributes_meta_box', NULL, 'side', 'core');
    }
}

function custom_page_attributes_meta_box($post) {
    $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', 1 ); ?>
    <select name="page_template" id="page_template">
        <?php $default_title = apply_filters( 'default_page_template_title',  __( 'Default Template' ), 'meta-box' ); ?>
        <option value="default"><?php echo esc_html( $default_title ); ?></option>
        <?php page_template_dropdown($template); ?>
    </select><?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_page_attributes_meta_box' );
function save_custom_page_attributes_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['page_template'] ) && get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'page' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', $_POST['page_template'] );
    }
}
```

So, the problem I'm facing now is how to display all the custom posts in my main page according to the chosen page template.

Thanks so much!
J

Comment: So basically you just want to know how to display custom posts on your main blog page, for you, the homepage?

Comment: No, I need to know how to make the custom post type display content according to the template chooser. Right now, this pulls all the content into the main page, however, the content is displayed according to a page template determined by the slug. I'd rather my client be able to choose how it's displayed from the template chooser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress actually only uses `_wp_page_template` meta field for page type posts. If you want to change the template, you can use the filter `single template`. One thing I would recommend is you place good notes that you are using this in your theme/ plugin....

btw update `cpt` to your post-type

```
function load_cpt_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

     if ($post->post_type == 'cpt') {

          $new_template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ); 

          // if a blank field or not valid do nothing, load default..
          if( is_file($new_template) )
            $single_template = $new_template;
     }
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'load_cpt_template' );
```

Comment: Should I replace the whole loop in the code with this or simply start at the `global $post`?

Comment: no just place in your functions file, its not part of the loop, it will look for the meta value _wp_page_template on your custom post type and load the template instead of the normal process.

Comment: thanks. My next question becomes how to pull all the posts together and display them in the page with their page templates. Any ideas on that end?

Comment: that's a new question really! if this one is done, please upvote/ accept and post a new question for that. I would attempt it yourself, `include()` or wordpress `get_template_part()` the page template in your loop. You will have issues with the post variable, but you should be able to overcome it.